# How to Get data from previous date and future date in flutter api call

Tags: flutter

I am working on an app for event management, I want to retrieve event data from api call for past date and future date.

I am using the below code. But no luck.

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getPastEventsData() async {
    var token = box.read('token');

    try {
      final response = await get(
        BaseClient().apiUrl.toString() +
            'api/event/?event_date<' +
            DateFormat('y-MM-d').format(DateTime.now()),
        headers: {'Authorization': 'token $token'},
      );
      if (response.status.hasError) {
        return Future.error(response.statusText.toString());
      } else {
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      return Future.error(exception.toString());
    }
  }


Future<List<dynamic>> getFutureEventsData() async {
    var token = box.read('token');

    try {
      final response = await get(
        BaseClient().apiUrl.toString() +
            'api/event/?event_date>' +
            DateFormat('y-MM-d').format(DateTime.now()),
        headers: {'Authorization': 'token $token'},
      );
      if (response.status.hasError) {
        return Future.error(response.statusText.toString());
      } else {
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      return Future.error(exception.toString());
    }
  }
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = Uri.parse(SystemConfiguration.baseUrl +
          SystemConfiguration.leaveCalenderEndpoint);
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          "pageSize": 100,
          "pageIndex": 0,
          "fromDate": DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime(
              DateTime.now().year - 2,
              DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day)),
          "toDate": DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime(
              DateTime.now().year + 2,
              DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day))
        }),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
        },
      );
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tasnuva oshin for your answer, though I have solved the problem in alternate way: Through a filter action in my resulted list of API response in my view part. The working code is as below:

For past data:

```
_eventController.eventData.where((e) => DateTime.parse(e['event_date'])
                                                .isBefore(DateTime.parse(
                                                DateFormat('y-MM-d').format(
                                                    DateTime.now()))))
                                                .toList()
```

For future data:

```
_eventController.eventData.where((e) => DateTime.parse(e['event_date'])
                                                .isAfter(DateTime.parse(
                                                DateFormat('y-MM-d').format(
                                                    DateTime.now()))))
                                                .toList()
```

`eventData` is my resulted list from the API call response.